# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, Node js

Tags: node.js

I am using Nodejs, Expess, MySql database and a React frontend. I am getting `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` when making an API call. I have looked at other questions regarding this issue and they all say that there needs to be a return statement to end the response. I have return statement so, I am not understanding what is wrong that is generating the error. Essentially what I am trying to do is to query a table in the database to get an id and then use the id received in another query to store data in a different table in the database. How can I do that without triggering the error?

Here is the API method:

```
app.post('/registerInCourse', (req, res) => {
  const cd = [req.body.code];
  const sId = [req.body.studentId];
  const sqlCode = "SELECT idCourses FROM stumgmtdb.Courses WHERE courseCode = ?"
  const sql = "INSERT INTO stumgmtdb.Registry (stuId, courId) VALUES (?,?)"; 
   
  let courseId = db.query(sqlCode, cd, (err,result)=> {
    if(err){
      return res.json({message: "Could not get course ID. " + err});
    }else {
      return res.json(result);
    }
  });

  const values = [
    sId,
    courseId.idCourses
  ]

  db.query(sql, values, (err,result)=> {
    if(err){
      return res.json({message: "Could not add student to the course " + err});
    }else {
      return res.json({message: "Student added successfully to the course"});
    }
  });
   
});
```

And here is the error message being generated:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:652:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:278:15)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/index.js:160:18)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/Jaculine/ReactProjects/Student-Results-Management-System/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return res` occurring twice in your code.

Consider writing your code in the following manner:

```
app.post('/registerInCourse', (req, res) => {
    const cd = [req.body.code];
    const sId = [req.body.studentId];
    const sqlCode = "SELECT idCourses FROM stumgmtdb.Courses WHERE courseCode = ?"
    const sql = "INSERT INTO stumgmtdb.Registry (stuId, courId) VALUES (?,?)";

    let courseId = db.query(sqlCode, cd, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ message: "Could not get course ID. " + err });
        } else {
            const values = [
                sId,
                courseId.idCourses
            ]

            db.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({ message: "Could not add student to the course " + err });
                } else {
                    return res.json({ message: "Student added successfully to the course", data: result });
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `return res` statements twice in my code? I thought that the return ends the response to the call and therefore you can make another api call.